# likely bug in K&R stack example

Tags: c

In K&R book, Calc program's  stack has

```
#define MAXVAL 100
int sp =0;          /* next free stack position */
double val[MAXVAL]; /* value stack*/
/* push: push f onto value stack */
void push(double f) {
    if ( sp < MAXVAL )
        val[sp++] = f;
    else 
        printf ("error: stack full, can't push%g\n",f);
}
```

It can push 1 extra value causing stack overflow. It should be (sp < MAXVAL - 1).
But It is hard to believe such mistake in this book.

Comment: It is `sp++` not `++sp` !

Comment: Do you know the difference between prefix and postfix increment?

Comment: Think again, when `sp` is `99` (i.e. *equal* to `MAXVAL - 1` and still less than `MAXVAL`) it's still a valid index into the array.

Comment: Note that `sp` is incremented after you push, so no overflow happens.

Comment: Overall this chapter of the book is very bad and harmful reading, since it propagates bad programming practice, such as using global variables and using spaghetti design, with variables and functions scattered randomly in various unrelated files, all of them at file scope. It is best to avoid this chapter entirely, or indeed the whole book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a mistake. Assigning to `val[]` at indexes from `0` to `MAXVAL-1`, inclusive, is legal.

Note that `sp++` is a *post-increment* expression, meaning that `sp` is incremented *after* its value has been used for indexing `val[]`. Hence, there is no undefined behavior in this example.

Comment: thanks, sp is next free position, when sp == 99 still one more space. and at full sp is100.

Answer (score 0):

> It can push 1 extra value

No. `sp` can only have values from 0 to 99 or otherwise `val[sp++] = f;` won't get executed. I suspect that you need to study how the post-increment ++ operator works.

> causing stack overflow

No. The wording in the book is perhaps confusing you. `double val[MAXVAL];` is not allocated on the stack, but in a global RAM segment (usually called `.bss`). This array is called a "value stack" by the book. It is not the stack segment of your computer, but a stack ADT.

> It is hard to believe such mistake in this book

Not really, the book has an errata of several pages. You must have this errata next to you when reading it.